# Show that Borel $\sigma$-algebra is generated by all open sets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Show that $$\text{Borel } \sigma-\text{algebra } \text{is generated by all open sets of }\mathbb{R}$$
I'm trying to get it right. By defenition $\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the smallest σ-algebra containing all open sets of $\mathbb{R}$. (1): Am I right that if  $\sigma$-algebra is generated by $K$, hence $K\subset \sigma(K)$, but not vice versa?
Let $K_1=\{\text{all open sets of } \mathbb{R}\}$ and $K_2=\{(a,b): a < b\}, a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. And I know that $\sigma(K_2)=\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$. So I should prove that $\sigma(K_1)=\sigma(K_2)$, by showing: 
$$\sigma(K_1)\subset\sigma(K_2)$$
$$\sigma(K_2)\subset\sigma(K_1)$$
But I don't really know how to do that because $\sigma-$algebra isn't constructive object. I mean I can't just take some element and prove it's in the other set due to the definition of $K_1$. So what should I do then? I really don't have any clue

Comment: "generated by X" = "smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing X" = "intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing X"